# Angular 4: Update Sibling Component's Array on Submit

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 4 Project. I am building a simple message view. It is composed of 2 components and they both share one service.

Service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';

import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class MessageService {

     messageAPI: string = 'http://localhost:4201';

     constructor(public $http: Http) {}

     getUsers(){
          return this.$http.get(this.messageAPI + '/users?_sort=date&_order=asc')
               .map(res => res.json());
     }

     getMessages(){
          return this.$http.get(this.messageAPI + '/messages?_sort=date&_order=asc')
               .map(res => res.json());
     }

     createMessage(data){
          return this.$http.post(this.messageAPI + '/messages', data)
               .map(res => res.json());
     }

}
```

Component one: (the messages)

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {MessageService} from '../../services/message.service';

import { Message } from '../../interfaces/message.interface';

@Component({
     selector: 'app-messages',
     templateUrl: './messages.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./messages.component.css']
})
export class MessagesComponent implements OnInit {

     messages:Message[];

     constructor(private $messageService: MessageService) {}

     ngOnInit() {

          this.$messageService.getMessages().subscribe((response) => {
               this.messages = response;
          });

     }

}
```

Component 2: (Create Form)

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {MessageService} from '../../services/message.service';

import { Message } from '../../interfaces/message.interface';
import { User } from '../../interfaces/user.interface';

@Component({
     selector: 'app-create',
     templateUrl: './create.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./create.component.css']
})

export class CreateComponent implements OnInit {

     message:Message;
     users:User[];

     constructor(private $messageService: MessageService) {}

     ngOnInit() {
          this.message = {
               userId:'',
               message:'',
               date: new Date()
          };

          this.$messageService.getUsers().subscribe((response) => {
               this.users = response;
          });
     }

     sendMessage(){
          this.message.date = new Date();
          this.$messageService.createMessage(this.message).subscribe((response) => {
               console.log(response);
          });
     }

}
```

Here is how the app looks when rendered: 
[image]

My question is how do i get Component One (Messages view) updated with the newest message when Component Two (create form) is submitted and a new message is created?

Comment: By sharing the data via a common service that exposes it as an Observable from a BehaviorSubject that is updated with a new instance of the array that also contains the new message, and the component subscribes (and unsubscribes) to this Observable in the right lifecycle methods. The subscribe method will update the messages array in the component.

Comment: Or by simply emitting an event from an Observable in the service after the message has been created, so,that the list component can subscribe to this observable and reload the list of messages each time an event is emitted. https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service.

Comment: That sounds like a good explanation, can you share some example code illustrating your logic with me? i am new to Angular4.

Comment: The guide has an entire chapter on components interaction. I linked to it.

Comment: Also I wrote on my blog about how we've used this pattern: http://blog.jonrshar.pe/2017/Apr/09/async-angular-data.html